# Mpdf Error: Word is too long to fit in table -

Tags: html, html-table, mpdf, tr

I wrote an mpdf html with tables and it keeps sending me this error saying "Word is too long to fit in table - " no matter what's the length of strings I have in tds.

This is my code:[mpdf error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYRpo.jpg)
    -

```
$mpdf = new Mpdf([
    'default_font' => 'roboto',
    'table_error_report' => true
]);

$mpdf->SetHTMLFooter('
    <table width="100%">
       <tr><td style="text-align:left;"><strong>Joe Dree</strong></td></tr>
       <tr><td style="text-align:left;">5 years experience</td></tr>
       <tr><td style="text-align:left;">Web developer, Web designer, UX Designer</td></tr>
       <tr><td style="text-align:left;">New York, USA</td></tr>
   </table>
');

$mpdf->WriteHTML('<html style="font-weight:normal;"><body>
    <table style="width: 100%;border-collapse: collapse;">
       <tbody>');

$mpdf->WriteHTML('</tbody>
    </table></body></html>');

$mpdf->Output();
exit();
```

How can I fix this?Thank you

Comment: If you post images of code or error messages make sure you also copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly.

Comment: Hi @RolandWeisleder , thanks for the quick reply! let me copy the code

Comment: Why are you using the 'table_error_report' parameter? Without it, the code works as expected.

Comment: Hi @Finwe , I'm using it because I wanted to know why my tables are not well aligned!

Answer (score 0):

I found why I had this issue and I fixed it! I wasn't specific with the width percentages but now it works and it's all good.
Thank you.